# how to change a cell value in a chart that is embedded in a word document using C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, ms-word

I have a word document containing some text and two charts pasted from excel. I am using it as a template. I want to open the word document in C#, update chart data values and print the document. I can do all except being able to access the chart data. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (both V14). Here is my code:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("K.docx");

Word.InlineShape shape = wordDoc.InlineShapes[1];
Word.Chart chart = shape.Chart;

Excel.Workbook wb = chart.ChartData.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];
ws.Cells["E4"] = 90;

wordDoc.PrintOut();
wordDoc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

The fifth command produces this error:

> Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT:0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

UPDATE:
I solved the error in fifth command as follows:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("K.docx");

wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[1].Chart.ChartData.Activate();
Word.InlineShape shape = wordDoc.InlineShapes[1];
Word.Chart chart = shape.Chart;

Excel.Workbook wb = chart.ChartData.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
ws.Cells["E4"] = 90;

wordDoc.PrintOut();
wordDoc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

This time `ws.Cells["E4"] = 90;` produces the following error:

> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: +1 for providing the fix (wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes[1].Chart.ChartData.Activate();) to problem I was having

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ws.Range["E4"].FormulaR1C1 = 90;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
ws1.Cells[4, "E"].Value = 1000;
```

My problem which could happen also to people who need this feature : [Interop Word & Excel : Can't close an Excel workbook embedded in Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60788443/interop-word-excel-cant-close-an-excel-workbook-embedded-in-word-document)

Answer (score 0):

It is better use `Aspose.word` that be cracked dll
in this section (Shape shape = (Shape)document.GetChild(NodeType.Shape, 0, true);) you can use for loop to find all shapes in your word doc and add i instead of 0

```
Document document = new Document(MyDir + "input.docx");
Shape shape = (Shape)document.GetChild(NodeType.Shape, 0, true);
if (shape.HasChart)
{
  Chart chart = shape.Chart;
  chart.Series.Clear();
  String[] types = new String[] { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
  double[] values = new double[] { 10d, 7d, 5d };
  ChartSeries ser0 = chart.Series.Add("test", types, values);
}
```