# Interop Word & Excel : Can't close an Excel workbook embedded in Word document

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I got an error when i'm closing the Excel workbook embedded in a Word document. This document got only one Excel chart. Nothing else : texts, etc...

This is the code :

```
Application _application = new Application
{
    Visible = false,
};
object oFilename = fileName;
object oFormat = WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatXMLDocument;
_document = _application.Documents.Open(
     ref oFilename, ref _missing, ref _faux, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing,
     ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref oFormat, ref _missing, ref _faux,
     ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);

_document.Activate();

InlineShape shape1 = _document.InlineShapes[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Chart chart1 = shape1.Chart;
Workbook wb1 = chart1.ChartData.Workbook;
wb1.Application.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMinimized;
Worksheet ws1 = wb1.Worksheets["Graphe"];
ws1.Cells[2, "A"].Value = 1000;

// --- THIS IS THE LINE WHICH HANDLE EXCEPTION
wb1.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
// ---

_document.Close(ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);
_application.Application.Quit(ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);
```

Let's see the exception (seem to be useless..) :
Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

Stack trace :

```
à Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.Close(Object SaveChanges, Object Filename, Object RouteWorkbook)
à TestFile.Program.Main(String[] args) dans C:\[Users..]\MyProject\Program.cs :ligne 53
```

Thanks for your help,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround...

Replace :

```
wb1.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

With :

```
wb1 = null;
```

***/!\ BUT be careful about the Dispose of `wb1` because we are still talking about a COM object***